# Trying to add linear-gradient to a data base image, can i use a db image on css?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

So first im trying to create a linear gradient on a card, so i have a div that is a link, and has a background image. so what i want to do is to show the image without text and when i hover change the background to a darker tone and show the text.

or is there a way to use: background-image: 
`url(<%= project.photos.first %>` in my css file?

Tried to use css to set only the linear gradient to the background and so far is no results.

Even tried java script to select the div and add the linear-gradient in this format:

`linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.3))`

But is always replacing the url and i lose my image at the end.

My Home page:

```
<div class="col d-flex align-content-center flex-wrap card-category home-card-light" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0)), url(<%= project.photos.first %>)">
    <h2 class="card-title"><%= project.title %></h2>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The CSS

```
.home-card-light {
  height: 430px;
  width: 720px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: round;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  &:hover {
  height: 430px;
  width: 720px;
  background-size: contain !important;
  background-repeat: round !important;
    background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(23,34,40,0.5),
      rgba(13,23,54,0)
      ) !important;
  }
}
```

The code posted is creating the linear gradient but replacing the image with it.

Comment: You can use `:after` and do that. Have updated the sname in the below snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `:after`

```css
.img-gradient {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-gradient:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(23,34,40,0.5) 0%, rgba(220, 66, 37, 0.5) 100%);
}

.img-gradient img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-gradient">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/la.jpg" width="400" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You! It works, now i have to find out how to exclude the text from taking the gradient and only to apply the gradient when i hover!